# Tooltip hiding in table with fixed header

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have a table with a fixed header, the tooltip is hidden by a neighboring cell on hover.

https://jsfiddle.net/9uep5na8/

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

td, th {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

button:hover::after {
    content: "some tooltip content";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 250px;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    min-width: 240px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive the only way is to use javaScript.

This is my implementation:

CSS:

```
#tooltip::after {
  content: "some tooltip content some tooltip content some tooltip content some tooltip content";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px 8px;
  min-width: 240px;
  max-width: 240px;
}
```

JS:

```
btn.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
})

btn.addEventListener('mouseout', event => {
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1dvc6mbh/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have a higher z-index for the `<th>` that has the tooltip

```
th.tooltip-header {
  z-index: 20;
}
```

Modified your example:
https://jsfiddle.net/0cwahnby/2/

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove the `position: absolute;` on your tooltip.